# MATLAB Adding Gaussian fit to histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, curve-fitting, gaussian

I am trying to add Gaussian fit to the histogram in MATLAB, but I do not know how to apply the fit to one particular peak only.

http://postimg.org/image/phms61rdh/ first plot

http://postimg.org/image/sindrn8er/ second plot

I am also posting part of the code I have been using:

```
    data_Rb = (importdata('path\name.txt'));
    counts_Rb = data_Rb.data(:,3);
    figure
    hist(counts_Rb, nbins);
    xlim([0 120]);
    title('Rubidium');
    histfit(counts_Rb,1000);

    pd=fitdist(counts_Rb(:),'normal')
    x=0:0.001:120;  
    PDF=pdf(pd,x); %PDF is a vector of y values: it's our fit
    PDF=PDF/max(PDF); %nor
    y=ylim;
    PDF=PDF*y(2);
    hold on
    plot(x,PDF,'r-','LineWidth',2);
    hold off
```

These two blocks give me two different Gaussians as shown in the first picture. I do not understand why they fit data so badly: is it because of the tail on the RHS?

In the second plot I need to apply Gaussian fit to the last peak only. How should I do it?

And finally, after applying the fit, fit results are outputed onto the screen. Is there a function to save them into an array or so for later use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look into MATLAB's Gaussian mixture model, described on http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last question, see [How can I access the fitted distribution parameters from the HISTFIT function in Statistiics Toolbox ?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-9XIWNC/?product=ML&solution=1-9XIWNC)

> There is a workaround for this isssue by making a copy of the HISTFIT
>   function and modifying the code to pass out the "pd" variable. One way
>   to do this is to change the "h" output on the first line of the code
>   to "varargout" and add the following to the end of the file:

```
h = [hh; hh1];
argout={h,pd};
if nargout > length(argout)
error('Too many output arguments.');
end
[varargout{1:nargout}]=argout{1:nargout};
```